# NodeJS, How to force the async for loop to wait the HTTP request to resolve before passing to the next iteration so we don't get the EMFILE error?

Tags: node.js, http, for-loop, asynchronous, foreach

I am trying to integrate into a custom API, I am getting some rows from the database and then for each row I am connecting to the API. 
Thing is when the database return 3000 rows or less the API returns the correct responses, when I get to POST more than 3000 I get the following:

[EMFILE ERROR -> OS won't allow the opening of more sockets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elh5C.png)

I believe the API won't allow more than 3000 HTTP requests
I tried the promise/async-await approach to wait for the HTTP request to end with no luck the only time it worked when I added a sleep function to wait 200 ms or more

Here my original function:

```
    async function send_data(rows){
    let a=0;    
    log.info("Emails to integrate: "+rows.length);
    if(rows.length){
      for(const row of rows){
        log.info(row.email+" --- "+row.name+" --- "+row.id);
        await integrate_data(row,a);
        //await sleep(50);
        a++;
      }
      log.info("Finished integration, setting last ID");
    } else {
      log.info("No data to integrate");
    }
}

function integrate_data(row,counter){
        var options = {
          "method": "POST",
          "hostname": "API-URL",
          "path":"PATH/EMAIL/"+row.email,
          "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        };
        var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
          var chunks = [];

          res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
          });

          res.on("end", function () {
            var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            log.info(body.toString());
          });
        });

        let obj;
          obj = { 
            key1: row.name,
            key2: row.id, 
            key3: row.iterationNumber
         }

        req.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
        req.end();
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

is there anyway to wait for the HTTP transaction to finish and then go to the next iteration so the function can open the connection, push data, close the connection and then give a signal to go to the next iteration?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await integrate_data(...)` isn't doing what you think. You're not waiting until the request is done, your code will execute

```
req.write(JSON.stringify(obj)); 
req.end();
```

and go to the next iteration.

For `await` to work as expected, `integrate_data` must return a `Promise`, and should resolve when the request finishes.

```
function integrate_data(row, counter) {
    var options = {
        "method": "POST",
        "hostname": "API-URL",
        "path": "PATH/EMAIL/" + row.email,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
          var chunks = [];

          res.on('error', reject);

          res.on("data", function(chunk) {
              chunks.push(chunk);
          });

          res.on("end", function() {
              var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
              log.info(body.toString());
              resolve(body.toString()); // resolve promise
          });
      });

      let obj;
      obj = {
          key1: row.name,
          key2: row.id,
          key3: row.iterationNumber
      }

      req.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
      req.end();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Marcos Casagrande it is working like charm

Comment: Indeed I am new to SO as well to NodeJS and the Async/Await/Promise concept. I accepted the answer thank you again man